# Headless Music Center

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, music, kodi, home-theatre

I have a small PC running Ubuntu 18.04 which is usually not connected to a monitor. It is an UpBoard ([details](https://up-shop.org/home/81-up-gws01w4g-memory32g-emmc-boardwo-vesa-plate.html))

I connected the audio output to my amplifier.

Playing music works if I connect a monitor to the upBoard.

My goal: use the upBoard in headless mode. I would like to choose music with some android device, and then the upBoard should play the songs I selected.

I looked at kodi, but this seems to be for TV output (not headless).

I am unsure which kind of software is needed ..

- for the upBoard?
- for the android device?

The audio files which I want to play are on the UpBoard, not on the android device.

Comment: Gmediarenderer should work fine: https://askubuntu.com/questions/963992/stream-all-audio-from-my-android-phone-to-pulseaudio

Comment: @Takkat The audio files which I want to play are on the UpBoard, not on the android device. Does gmediarenderer work for this case, too?

Comment: `mpd` can work for you if you are interested in music alone. Install the server on the board then use the mpdroid android app as a remote control

Comment: @ptetteh227 mpd sound good. Please write your comment as answer, then I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [here](https://www.musicpd.org/)

> Music Player Daemon (MPD) is a flexible, powerful, server-side
>   application for playing music. Through plugins and libraries it can
>   play a variety of sound files while being controlled by its network
>   protocol.

It is available in the ubuntu 18.04 repo:

```
sudo apt install mpd
```

after installing mpd create the conf file:

```
sudo cat /etc/mpd.conf | tee ~/.mpdconf
```

create the mpd dir and some files:

```
mkdir /home/$USER/Music/mpd
mkdir /home/$USER/Music/mpd/playlists
touch /home/$USER/Music/mpd/{mpd.log,tag_cache,pid}
```

edit the conf file:

```
nano ~/.mpdconf
```

and change appriopriate portions to the values here

```
music_directory     "/home/USER/Music"
playlist_directory      "/home/USER/Music/mpd/playlists"
db_file         "/home/USER/Music/mpd/tag_cache"
log_file            "/home/USER/Music/mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "/home/USER/Music/mpd/pid"
state_file          "/home/USER/Music/mpd/state"
sticker_file                   "/home/USER/Music/mpd/sticker.sql"
#user               "mpd"
bind_to_address     "0.0.0.0"
port                "6600"
#save_absolute_paths_in_playlists   "no"
#auto_update    "yes"
#zeroconf_enabled       "yes"
#zeroconf_name          "MPD Music Player"
#password                        "password@read,add,control,admin"

audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
{
filesystem_charset      "UTF-8"
```

It is importtant to that the user parameter is commented else you may get errors during running.
Also replace USER with your username

Then kill mpd from running systemwide:

```
sudo pkill mpd
sudo systemctl disable mpd
```

and make it start on login:
~/.config/autostart/mpd.desktop

and paste

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Music Player Daemon
Comment=Server for playing audio files
Exec=mpd
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

now start the music server:

```
mpd
```

Download the android app [mpdroid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.namelessdev.mpdroid/)

Afterwards connect both android and the board to the same network. start mpddroid and enter your servers ip and mpd port (6600). Firewall ports should also be properly setup to allow the android client access

refenence:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD

Comment: Thank you very much. MPD works great. But I used the default daemon started via systemd (not at user level). I needed to change "listen" to "any" and everything worked fine. Unfortunately the daemon does not detect new audio files on his own. You need to restart the daemon. I use MALP on android, there is a button to reload the library. Again: Thank you, MPD works very nice.